# change npm package description

Tags: npm, npmjs

I published a package to npm last night through the npm cli. When I published it, I wasn't careful to review the description I wrote, and now there's a typo in it.

I can't find a way to change the description. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to release a new version in order to change the description.